# moving a jQuery / heavy dom based site to AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

This will be a bit of an open-ended question but would appreciate any advice that a more-experienced AngularJS developer could provide. This would be a pretty big decision so thought I would ask here for any help. Feel free to ignore if you don't like these types of questions.

We have a fairly heavy DOM based jquery site. Our company is interested in using a framework to simplify development. Even looking at our current jQuery site, it would seem like we could just move this functionality into Angular and remove the initial event binding to DOM elements with ng-click or other appropriate event. While this would leave still a fairly large dependency on the DOM for maintaining state, it would get us on the road to using something more structured. Would doing this seem like a reasonable step?

A lot of our code would be transferred to something like this:

html:

```
<button ng-click="saveItem($event)" type="button" class="save-item-changes btn" data-global-id="205" style="">save changes</button>
```

javascript:

```
$scope.saveItem=function(event){
  var global_id_val=$(event.target).data('global-id');
   //alert('here is global_id:' + global_id_val);

  var header_val=$('#menu-item-header-' + global_id_val).val();
  var detail_val=$('#menu-item-detail-' + global_id_val).val();
  var position_val=$('#menu-item-position-' + global_id_val).val();
  $http({
    url:'/arc/v1/api/save-item',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {header: header_val, detail: detail_val, position: position_val, global_id: global_id_val}
  }).success(function(r){  
    if(r.is_moved==true){
   // do the dom manipulations here
  }).error(function(r){
  // handler error here
  });
```

A few reasons I like it are that going forward on this app we can use Angular and it forces us to at least figure out what is being used and what isn't. I know we probably won't get all the testing benefits due to DOM dependence but you have to start somewhere. Potential downsides that I see are "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" and possibly some browser issues with IE pre-8 but to be honest, IE issues would be modest. Does anyone have any sage advice on this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal opinion is that it would certainly be a good initial step; it would introduce slowly angular without having to port the entire application in one go. Depending on the size of the project and the resources you are willing to put into refactoring the application, I think it would also be important to convert the manual DOM operations to use data binding instead..

You probably also want to put in quarantine your old DOM operation code so you keep your angular controllers clean while keeping in mind the old jQuery DOM code needs to be ported.

Comment: Thx for answer. Would definitely like to pull the DOM operations out but even the structure afforded by ng-controller seems to already be helpful in terms of decreasing technical debt. I had a similar situation with a massive php app like 7 years ago when we just started porting pieces into Zend Framework. It utlimately was the best decision for the app and am hoping for a similar benefit here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to take a second and rewrite your code. It's not how you do angular. Here's a simple approach.

So, first up, *do not perform DOM manipulations in your controller*. Ever. Angular is really good at two way binding and you should let it do it's job. Handle updating data and letting angular respond to the changes.

You start with an object, you manipulate the object, and you save the object. You do not bother pulling and setting values with jQuery. Doing so pretty much destroys any point of using Angular.

Here's what a simple implementation of your example would look like.

**Html:**

```
<div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="settings.saved">Saved!</div>

    Header: <input ng-model="item.header" type="text" />
    Detail: <input ng-model="item.header" type="text" />
    Position: <input ng-model="item.header" type="text" />
    <a ng-click="saveItem(item)" class="save-item-changes btn">save changes</a>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function ItemCtrl ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.settings = {
        saved: false
    }

    $scope.item = {
        global_id: 1,
        global_val: 'global'
        header: 'header',
        detail: 'detail',
        position: 'position',
    }

    $scope.saveItem = function (item) {
        $http({
            url:'/arc/v1/api/save-item',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $scope.item
        }).success(function (r) {
            $scope.settings.saved = true; 
        }.error(function (e) {
            // Error handler
        })

    }               
}
```

Comment: thx Mike, I really appreciate. I definitely want to be there but even migrating what we currently have seems to give us some benefit. This particular pieces is a bit thorny where there's a bunch of nesting (like acts_as_tree) in rails

Comment: why the downvotes - i upvoted so 2 people downvoted with no comment?

Comment: @timpone I wondered too. Is there a bug I missed?

Comment: I don't think so since normally there is such glee in pointing things like that out. I figured people don't like my question since kinda braod but that's why I had the first paragraph. thx again for help, a big jump for us and I appreciate the help.

Comment: @timpone Good luck, and TAKE THE TUTORIALS. Learn how Angular does things before injecting it into your application.

Comment: thx, I've read through them and read AngularJS in Action MEAP. I feel for what we are trying to do, this will get us by but will definitely have questions.